# Wait until all Future.onComplete callbacks are executed

Tags: scala, future

I am using the `Future` API from Scala 2.10.X.

Here is my use case:

```
object Class1 {

  def apply(f: (Int) => Future[String])(i: Int): Future[String] = {

    val start = DateTime.now

    val result = f(i)

    result.onComplete{
      case _ => println("Started at " + start + ", ended at " + DateTime.now)
    }

    result
  }
}
```

Pretty simple I think: I'm adding an onComplete callback to my future. Now, I'm wondering if there is a way to add a callback for when the onComplete is done executing - in this example know when the logging is done.

Let's say my `result` instance has 3 `onComplete` registered, can I know when all of them have been executed? I don't think it's possible but who knows :)

Maybe an alternative would be to call `map` instead of `onComplete` to return a new instance of `Future`:

```
def apply(f: (Int) => Future[String])(i: Int): Future[String] = {

  val start = DateTime.now

  f(i) map {
    case r => 
      println("Started at " + start + ", ended at " + DateTime.now)
      r
  }
}
```

But I am not sure it would keep the same behavior.

Edit: Just to clarify - there is only **one** instance of `Future`, and I call `onComplete` 3 times on the *same* instance (Well, in my example only once, but let's say I'm calling it N times) and I want to know when the 3 callbacks are done executing due to the completion of the same `Future` instance.

Comment: Hold on, I might have answered this wrong. Are you saying you have 1 `Future` and you've done `onComplete` 3 times or 3 `Future` each with an `onComplete`? 'Cause if it's the second, my answer is rubish.

Comment: @wheaties See my edit: yes, there is only one Future and we call onComplete N times on the same instance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't want to use other methods (like a CountDownLatch), then you want to use `andThen` to know when your operations complete (successfully or not, and whether or not the Future was successful).

```
scala> val f = Future(3)
f: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@4b49ca35

scala> val g = f andThen { case Success(i) => println(i) } andThen { case _ => println("All done") }
3
g: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@1939e13
All done
```

If the future fails, the mapped function by contrast isn't invoked:

```
scala> val f = Future[Int](???)
f: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@7001619b

scala> val g = f andThen { case t => println(s"stage 1 $t") } andThen { case _ => println("All done") }
stage 1 Failure(java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Boxed Error)
All done
g: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@24e1e7e8

scala> val g = f map { case i => println(i) } andThen { case _ => println("All done") }
All done
g: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@5d0f75d6

scala> val g = f map { case i => println(i) } map { case _ => println("All done") }
g: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@5aabe81f

scala> g.value
res1: Option[scala.util.Try[Unit]] = Some(Failure(java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Boxed Error))
```

Similarly, blowing up in a chained handler doesn't break subsequent operations:

```
scala> val g = f andThen { case t => null.hashCode } andThen { case _ => Thread.sleep(1000L); println("All done") }
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at $line26.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(<console>:51)
    at $line26.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(<console>:51)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Future.scala:431)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Future.scala:430)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
g: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@3fb7bec8

scala> All done


scala> g.value
res1: Option[scala.util.Try[Int]] = Some(Success(3))
```

For the unfortunate case of needing to wait for it:

```
scala> val f = Future[Int](???)
f: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@859a977

scala> import java.util.concurrent.{ CountDownLatch => CDL }
import java.util.concurrent.{CountDownLatch=>CDL}

scala> val latch = new CDL(3)
latch: java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch = java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@11683e9f[Count = 3]

scala> f onComplete { _ => println(1); latch.countDown() }
1

scala> f onComplete { _ => println(2); latch.countDown() }
2

scala> f onComplete { _ => println(3); latch.countDown() }
3

scala> f onComplete { _ => latch.await(); println("All done") }
All done
```

Comment: Good call! I totally forgot that `map` would be ignored if the Future or any of the callbacks happened to fail during the execution.

Answer (score 5):

**With 1 Future and 3 onComplete**

I think you're going to have to go the route of either composing your functions into a single `onComplete` call or else you'll have to do exactly what you said, use `map`:

```
 val fut1 = myFut map func1 // yes, a Future[Unit]
 val fut2 = myFut map func2
 val fut3 = myFut map func3
```

Follow the next section to find out when they all finish.

**With 3 different Futures**

It's very possible to know when all three `Future`s will complete. In fact, in Scala `Future` composes!

```
 def threeFutures(one: Future[Int], two: Future[Int], three: Future[Int]) {
   val fourth = for {
     _ <- one
     _ <- two
     _ <- three
   } yield 0

   fourth onComplete {
     case _ => println("all done")
   }
 }
```

Now what does this mean? It means that `fourth` is a `Future` which does not care about the inputs of the three arguments but that, when they all are complete, it will complete itself. This is pre-packaged and made ready just for you.

(Side note: In the example I'm also assuming you have all your implicits in scope.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that the problem remains even with only one `onComplete`, I still can't find a way to know when this registered callback is done executing. I think you're right, `map` would work because then, when my `Future` completes I know that the code in `map` is done running.

Comment: @vptheron This isn't quite correct for the reasons I give. You won't see when failed futures complete.  I think the best solution is another sync primitive, like a latch so when the last completer is done, you kick off whatever you want to do next, rather than blocking for it.

Comment: @som-snytt: this solution works just fine: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/SZ5Dspu7).

Comment: @senia That doesn't print 1,2,3, right? So those aren't run as side-effecting callbacks, as in onComplete. I think that was the use case, to know when they complete (after running, that is).