# Scala Future oncomplete doesn't complete?

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand higher order functions in scala futures. I wrote this piece of code

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global


object App30 extends App {

  def getMilk(): String = {
    val ans = "5 gallons of milk"
    ans
  }
  def getFlour(): String =
  {
    val ans= "2 oz of flour"
    ans
  }

  val milkFuture = Future { getMilk() }
  val flourFuture = Future { getFlour() }

  val resultFut = {
    for {
      milk <- milkFuture
      flour <- flourFuture
      result = milk + flour
    } yield result
  }

  resultFut.onComplete{

    case Success(answer) => println("The result of getting ingridents is " + answer)
    case Failure(exception) =>  println("could not access future value")
  }
}
```

My issue is that I am not able to get the required string 'the result of getting ...' . I see that the debugger stops with onComplete and does not proceed to successful case.

May I know where I am going wrong? If this was a silly mistake, kindly point it out and I will take down the question after that. Else, provide with an explanation on what concept is amiss as this will help newcomers.

Thanks

Comment: This has many duplicates, such as https://stackoverflow.com/q/21188012/1296806 and relatedly your question https://stackoverflow.com/q/45447679/1296806

Comment: there are other questions of greater befuddlement over the process exiting when side effects haven't completed. But I'm at the office and can't look for them.

Answer (score 2):

You have to explicitly block on the future, otherwise the main thread might terminate before its completion:

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

Await.result(resultFut, 5 seconds)
```

Note such methods should definitely not be used with production code, it is merely for testing the output of the `Future`. Usually, you'll have some event loop running endlessly in the background where the future will have a chance to complete, unless something bad happens.

Comment: hi, may I know how to make onComplete to block the main thread until the value is obtained from future without using await.result. thanks

Comment: You can't make `onComplete` block, as it's a side effect applied to the Future, it doesn't return a value. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question?